# I am the emptiness that fills - What am I?

Tags: riddle, homonym

Feel me rise in anger,

I am the emptiness that fills,

An obstruction, I may choke you,

Yet many enjoy me.

**What am I?**

Comment: is it related to smoke?

Comment: I know I know I know -- you are Brent Hackers. (Or is that not the answer this time? Damn.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Cheeky bugger. +1 >:|

Comment: @smriti Nowt to do with smoke.  Sorry.

Comment: Noticing the tag [tag:homonym], I'm guessing the answer has a different meaning to explain each line.

Comment: @engineertoast Not a different meaning for each 'line' exactly but yes, the descriptions aren't all of the same thing but rather of the word that they have in common.

Comment: I don't see any actual homonyms here...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan If you mean in the actual question, that's because it's the answer that's a homonym.  If you mean that I'm using the word wrong, then quite possibly.  Sorry.  I do know that there are some specific words for words that are spelled the same vs sound the same etc. but I know homonym gets used as a sort of umbrella term which is good because I have to google the others if I want to use them.

Comment: I think everything here is multiple meanings of a single word, whereas homonyms are different words that sound the same. (But may or may not be spelled the same.) So e.g. "ate" and "eight" are homonyms (spelled differently); "tick" the insect and "tick" the checkmark are homonyms (spelled the same); "tick" the checkmark and "tick" the verb meaning to draw one are just different meanings of a single word.

Comment: (But yeah, looking at the description of the "homonym" tag it looks like it's used more broadly, so my apologies for nitpicking.)

Comment: You are the holes that fill the Albert Hall.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps you are a

> GORGE.

Feel me rise in anger,

> To say that someone's gorge rises is to say that they are either violently disgusted or very angry.

I am the emptiness that fills,

> A gorge is a sort of canyon (an emptiness in the ground) carved out by a river (so if the river floods, the gorge can fill with water). Also, to gorge on some sort of food is to eat a great deal of it and fill yourself up.

An obstruction, I may choke you,

> If your gorge (your throat) is obstructed, you may choke. (I think this is the weakest fit in this answer.) OR: the dictionary tells me there's a US-only usage: "A mass choking up a narrow passage; esp. in ice-gorge" which seems like it fits fairly well.

Yet many enjoy me.

> Many people like to gorge themselves -- on, say, ice cream or steak.

Comment: Bingo! House! Checkmate! Etc!  You missed a meaning that better covers the 'obstruction' but you got it.  +1

Comment: OK, I've added another candidate for that.

Comment: That's the one.  I had no idea it was US only...  I will stop using it promptly.  Colour! Aluminium! Lift! Etc!

Comment: Of course the OED could be wrong about it being US-only -- it's sometimes rather out of date. It's not a usage I've heard, but that proves nothing at all.

Comment: @BrentHackers Beware, "Colour" is UK!

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος That was the point.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος: You misspelt "English".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I hate "phantom" replies. Where did I mis-spell it?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος He's suggesting that British English is the "real" English.

Comment: @jpmc26 Hmm... BAD PUN! BAAAAD, BAAAAAAAAD PUN!

Answer (score 8):

You are a

> donut

Feel me rise in anger,

> I throw food when I'm angry

I am the emptiness that fills,

> Donuts have a hole and they fill me up

An obstruction, I may choke you,

> Too many donuts may cause choking

Yet many enjoy me.

> God knows I enjoy donuts

Comment: I like it but it's not the answer.  But proper ones have jam, not a hole! -1000

Answer (score 6):

Apologies in advance because this is certainly NOT the answer

(NSFW Warning)

> **A Penis**
> *Feel me rise in anger,*
>  Some people have erections when angry... Don't ask me how I know this
> *I am the emptiness that fills,*
>  Don't want to explain this
> *An obstruction, I may choke you,*
>  Uhhh... Yeah, REALLY don't want to explain that one...
> *Yet many enjoy me.*
>  Pretty self explanatory...

Sorry again...

Comment: Another one... You should be ashamed.  Not the worst fit so far though.  (I know, I know, "that's what she said")

Answer (score 6):

You already selected an answer but

> Pressure

In anger,

> blood pressure rises.

Emptiness that fills

> a balloon or tire

Choke:

> Some people choke under pressure.

Some people enjoy it.

> Indeed, some people do best under pressure

Comment: Pretty damn good...  Guess I should've spent longer on this one.  +1

Answer (score 5):

Bit of a stretch, but are you perhaps:

> feelings/emotions?

Feel me rise in anger,

> Becoming angry could be described as having raised or heightened emotions.

I am the emptiness that fills,

> Being filled with feelings of emptiness?

An obstruction, I may choke you,

> You can be choked up with emotion.

Yet many enjoy me.

> I certainly hope people enjoy having emotions in general, especially the happy ones, even if not all the time.

Comment: Not awful fits. +1 not what I'm after though.  The answer is a single word that has more than one meaning.

Answer (score 4):

Apologies in advance and I am hesitant to answer for being tricked but are you ..

> Dam

I was going to say

> Damn, it's not Brent Hackers

Feel me rise in anger

> Dam risen is mad

I am the emptiness that fills

> A dam is a reservoir that is filled with hopefully water

An obstruction, I may choke you

> A dam is an obstruction in say a river and Choke dam is in Texas and creates a large reservoir.

Yet many enjoy me

> Dams can be nice places for sight seeing, fishing e.t.c and also enjoyed for the water it provides

Comment: I don't have a clue what you're talking about...  But not a terrible guess.  +1

Comment: I'm glad I got this wrong - nothing unusual in that -  it was bad but not as much as some I see or am sure! have seen earlier. My first thought was smoke but considered that as a smokescreen: - nice to see some of the other answers anyhow!. What's happening to the world these days ...

Answer (score 4):

Are you...

> air

Feel me rise in anger,

> Air rises when it gets hot, when people get angry they get hot tempered

I am the emptiness that fills,

> Air is generally considered as something being empty or not present and yet it is a gas that fills up whatever contains it.

An obstruction, I may choke you,

> If our airflow is obstructed we will choke

Yet many enjoy me.

> We need air to live

Comment: Not an awful fit but not the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I am just guessing here.. I think it's

> Tie

Feel me rise in anger,

> In anger, we sometimes raise our chin, in turn raising the tie

I am the emptiness that fills,

> I m not sure about this but I think, it probably fills the space on our shirt below the chin.

An obstruction, I may choke you

> Fit it too tight and it will choke u

Yet many enjoy me.

> Still people like to put on tie for a better appearance(not me)

Comment: Sorry.  Not what I'm after but that first explanation is close-ish.  (physically at least) +1

Answer (score 3):

Second try :

> heart

Feel me rise in anger,

> when you get angry, you feel your heart racing/pouncing

I am the emptiness that fills,

> an heart is empty, but keep getting filled with blood

An obstruction, I may choke you,

> When there is a bloodclot, it block the body to access oxygen -> choke

Yet many enjoy me.

> we say that a nice personne is a heart person (at least in French, but i think i've heard something similar in english)

Comment: I apologies for my last answer, I really posted it in good faith.

Comment: A much better try +1 but still not what I'm looking for.  I don't think your answer (in a living thing at least) is ever actually "empty" is it?  Anyway, 'choke' is more literal.  There's your own personal little clue, just for you.

Answer (score 3):

Feel me rise in anger,

> When one is angry, they push those closest away, becoming lonely

I am the emptiness that fills,

> Loneliness becomes overwhelming

An obstruction, I may choke you,

> Loneliness is terribly choking to some people.  Also can lead to one not doing much (an obstruction).

Yet many enjoy me.

> I myself enjoy being an introvert.

Comment: Huh.  A seriously good fit...  +1  Not the answer though.

Answer (score 3):

Well, is that possible you are a

> geyser

?

Feel me rise in anger,

> Surely when I become angry, I rise !

I am the emptiness that fills,

> I am just a hole... but also filled by water

An obstruction, I may choke you,

> Sure let me spring !

Yet many enjoy me.

> I am so spectacular : )

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Could you edit this answer to add in an explanation as to why you think it is correct?

Comment: mmm... ok... sorry first time in this stack

Comment: @Emrakul, Is that better ?

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely an improvement! Thanks for the quick edits, and welcome again!

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Whole/Hole

Feel me rise in anger,

> Sometimes when people get mad they may punch a **hole** in the wall

I am the emptiness that fills,

> A **hole** is empty, while **whole** is all of something (or a filled in **hole**)

An obstruction, I may choke you,

> "You ate the **whole** thing?"

Yet many enjoy me

> Donut **holes**

Comment: Clever but not what I'm looking for.  And no one enjoys the hole.  Especially me.  I like big puffy ones with no hole and lots of jam.